# synchronizing wikibase and neo4j

Tags: neo4j, wikidata, knowledge-graph, wikibase

recently I want to use wikibase as my knowledgebase and neo4j as knowledge graph, which gives me the ability to inferring on my knowledgebase. so I need to synchronizing wikibase and neo4j data and schema. How can I reach this goal ? is there any reliable way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neosemantic plugin is a way to sync wikibase with neo4j

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found an existing tool, you may have to write it yourself.

I just looked at the Wikibase home page; it's based on MediaWiki and has a SPARQL interface, so at first glance this is a very solvable problem.

Since Neo4j doesn't have a schema as such, there's at least one problem you won't have to solve :)